# Persisting data on Sap Hana using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl, hana

I'd like to understand a beahaviour I'm experiencing on sap hana.

I have Class A

```
package org.cl;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CLASS_A")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class ClassA implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLASS_A_ID")
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ClassB> classesB = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

and ClassB

```
package org.cl;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CLASS_B")
@Setter
@Getter
public class ClassB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CLASS_B_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CLASS_A_ID", nullable=false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private String classAId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASS_A_ID", referencedColumnName = "CLASS_A_ID")
    private ClassA classA;
}
```

if I apply this piece of code

```
List<ClassB> classBInstances = populateList(classAInstance);
classAInstance.setSlaves(classBInstances);
entityManager.merge(user);
```

1. if classBInstances is populated with only new instances, everything ok
2. if classBInstances is populated with a mixture of new and old elements, and some elements have been removed, inside the db I find all the original elements plus new ones
3. if all original elements have been removed and replaced by totally different and new instances, again in the db I find the original plus the new elements

To have things working properly, I have to explicitly remove from list and from db unwanted elements and then apply a persist for every new classB instance.

How can I fix the situation?

I would like to operate only using the lists, if an element does not appear in the list must be removed, if it appears must me persisted.

My system

- querydsl-jpa: 4.2.1
- querydsl-core: 4.2.1
- hibernate-core: 5.3.7
- sap hana db version: 1.00.122.06.1485334242
- java runtime: 8

Thanks in advance for the support

Comment: I think this is just the behaviour defined as per the JPA specification for cascading merge updates to collections. Probably you want to set `orphanRemoval = true` for your `OneToMany` association. Also read: https://vladmihalcea.com/merge-entity-collections-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks very much, it is the right answer!

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling: could you make that comment an answer, so it could be accepted making it better consumable for other users as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the behaviour defined as per the JPA specification for cascading merge updates to collections. Probably you want to set `orphanRemoval = true` for your `@OneToMany` association.

Also read: vladmihalcea.com/merge-entity-collections-jpa-hibernate